How to call the CMD from the registry to execute the "for" command
I tried to use "url protocol" to run my "CMD" in the Windows registry. Caz I wanna split the variables more accurately. It works when i use the set to split.
However,I wanna use for %a in (%s%) do echo %a in registry's CMD.
In the registry:
cmd /V:ON /k "for %a in (%s%) do echo %a"
when i access the url, the CMD's call is successful,but make an error.
At this time, there should be no %a. 
{(The process has been exited, the code is 1 (0x000000001)]]

I tried to use the command cmd /V:ON /k "for %a in (%s%) do echo %a", but it did not work.
I wanna split the variables more accurately in CMD.Such as for or others.

try using
for %%a in (%s%) do echo %%a

instead of:
for %a in (%s%) do echo %a

Double percent signs to pass them literally to a subprocess (instead of trying it to process it as "start of a variable"). The original line translates a in ( as an (empty) variable, same as ) do echo. %% is translated as a single % to the new instance, which then can process it correctly. (this is called "escaping")
This should help CMD interpret the variables correctly.
